# AWS Subnet CIDR in confliction

Tags: amazon-web-services, subnet

What's IP does not conflict with 172.31.0.0/16. I'm not a networking guy and would like to get this resolved.
I'm getting this error.
CIDR Address overlaps with existing Subnet CIDR: 172.31.0.0/20

Comment: What are you actually wanting to achieve? Are you creating multiple VPCs and you want the to talk to each other? Or are you wanting to create a `172.31.0.0/20` **subnet** within a `172.31.0.0/16` **VPC**?

Comment: Did you check e.g., [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIDR_notation)? Plenty of addresses don't overlap with a /16 CIDR.

Answer (score 4):

I highly recommend you use the tool below

https://tidalmigrations.com/subnet-builder/

it helped me to create hundreds of subnet designs

for 172.31.0.0/20 the IP range is 172.31.0.1 - 172.31.15.254

so you can use 172.31.16.0/20

Comment: Stack Overflow answers should not make tool recommendations, because answers here are supposed to be objective, as evidenced by the fact that questions asking for tool recommendations or otherwise opinion-based answers are [not among the content allowed, here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Additionally, if you do mention specific tools (other than as is sometimes necessary for an example or contrast, or for "official" or "canonical" tools like aws-cli) you do need to make it clear if you are in any way affiliated with what you're pitching (or not) to avoid being flagged for spam.

Answer (score 3):

`172.31.0.0/16` refers to every IP address that starts with `172.31.x.x`.

`172.31.0.0/20` refers to `172.31.0.0` to `172.31.15.255`.

There is an overlap between the two ranges.